# How do I dynamically set a max value on a number type in Thymleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working on a Ecommerce application and want to dynamically set the maximum amount of a product that can be added to a cart depending on the quantity that is left. my Html code is currently

```
<tr>
                    <th>quantity</th>
                    <td><input type="number" min="1" max="${product.stockQuantity}" value="1" name="qty" /></td>
                </tr>
```

This does not limit the amount that can be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `th:max` according to official documentation:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-attribute-values

Comment: You can apply the same strategy for all attributes you need in the future :)

Comment: @paulchew88 - If an answer was helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This step is optional, but strongly recommended.